# Using variable column names in object notation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm writting a function to generate HTML columns and I'm having some trouble with the syntax to use variable column names in a query.

```
<cffunction name="generateColumns" output=True> 
    <cfargument name="query">
    <cfargument name="numberOfColumns">
    <cfargument name="columnName">
    <cfargument name="linkVariable">
    <cfset html = ''>
    <cfset itemsPerColumn = Ceiling(query.recordCount/3)>
    <!--- Loop through each column --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#numberOfColumns#" index="outerIndex">
        <cfset html = html & '<ul class="icf_nav-iblock">'>
        <!--- Loop through the inner items --->
        <cfloop from="1" to="#itemsPerColumn#" index="innerIndex">
            <cfset totalIndex = ((outerIndex - 1) * itemsPerColumn) + innerIndex>
            <cfset link = createRegressiveLink("#linkVariable#",query["#columnName#"][totalIndex])>
            <cfset html = html & '<li data-id="' & query["#columnName#"][totalIndex] & '">'>
            <cfset html = html & '<a href="' & link & '" class="icf_btn_small">'>
            <cfset html = html & query["#columnName#"][totalIndex]>
            <cfset html = html & '</a>'>
            <cfset html = html & '</li>'>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset html = html & '</ul>'>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn html>
</cffunction>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Table (rows 10 columns VCHRMAKE): [VCHRMAKE: coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@1d3e7178] ] is not indexable by columnName
```

I have tried

```
query["#columnName#"][totalIndex] 
query["columnName"][totalIndex] 
query[columnName][totalIndex]
```

and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I made a stupid mistake when invoking the function. I passed the  "columnName" string as the name of the column. Turns out query[columnName][totalIndex] is the correct syntax.